# Linux host can't connect to docker container via localhost

Tags: postgresql, docker

I run the following to start a postgres server container:

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
```

What I was expecting was to use dbeaver to connect via localhost:5432 with postgres and mysecretpassword, but I keep getting the following error in dbeaver, indicating my credentials are wrong:

```
Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
  Connection refused
  Connection refused
```

Am I pointed at the right IP / port? -p doesn't help and neither does --add-host with host.docker.internal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just run `docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres`, the container is started but no ports are exposed. Add the parameter `-p 5432:5432` to forward your local port 5432 to port 5432 of the docker container:

`docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -p 5432:5432 -d postgres`

Now you can connect to postgres on `localhost:5432`. Using an ip address from `docker inspect` is not recommended because this ip address might change, for example when the container is recreated.

Comment: I tested your command and it did work. I plan to use this method in the future, since it's more explicit than my solution.

I had initially tried the following, but it failed because I ordered -p and -d differently: 

docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres -p 5432:5432

Answer (score -1):

Very simple fix for me, just replace localhost with:

```
172.17.0.2
```

localhost = 172.17.0.1, so no wonder that didn't work.

**How I solved it:**

I ran the following command to inspect the container details. Under Networks:bridge:IPAddress: I found the 172.17.0.2 address.

```
docker inspect {{CONTAINER_ID_GOES_HERE}}
```

Comment: `localhost` is defined as 127.0.0.1 and its meaning is very context-specific.  The `docker inspect` IP address happens to work on a native-Linux host directly running the Docker engine, but it doesn't work in any other context, and looking it up isn't usually a best practice.